# How to write values outside of [0, 1] to gl_FragData

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to write a view space position out through gl_FragData.

Unfortunately this value seems to be clamped [0-1]
(or at least it is when I read it back)

Is there a way not to clamp it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use floating point textures: GL_RGBA16F, GL_RGBA32F, etc... they are not clamped

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Floating_point_and_mipmapping_and_filtering

I use (for creating empty floating point texture):

```
glGenTextures(1, &texId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);        
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);    
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

Comment: +1 looking into this now. The documentation is misleading, as it suggests that the symbolic constants are the same as entering a value [1,4] (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml)

Comment: I have tested out using GL_RGB32F, and it indeed works as expected.

It is unfortunate that this enum does not show up on the documentation of glTexImage2D, I wonder who is in charge of updating that document.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a float color  buffer by using the [GL_ARB_color_buffer_float](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/color_buffer_float.txt) extension: fragments are stored using a floating-point format, and the result can be clamped/unclamped by enabling/disabling the `CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR_ARB` switch (using `ClampColorARB`).

Note that this is not a texture-based technique, but it defines a real color buffer. Sadly, this color buffer cannot be displayed on normal window (offscreen rendering).

---

Respect the [GL_ARB_texture_float](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_float.txt) extension, the GL_ARB_color_buffer_float allows the control of the clamping behavior of the fixed rendering pipeline (separating the vertex stage and the fragment stage).

However, defining a color buffer does not allow you to have multiple color buffers. Instead, using floating-point textures allows you to setup a more complex framebuffer object.

However, notice the following discussion from the texture_float extensions:

> Are floating-point values clamped for the fixed-function GL?
>
> ```
>    RESOLVED:  This extension introduces texel values that can be
>    outside [0, 1].  No clamping occurs to these values during
>    texture filtering.  For the fixed-function pipeline, the
>    filtered texel is now clamped before it is used for texture
>    environment blending.  The ARB_color_buffer_float extension
>    can be used to control this clamping.  For the programmable
>    pipelines, no clamping occurs.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable color clamping:

```
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_VERTEX_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
glClampColorARB(GL_CLAMP_FRAGMENT_COLOR_ARB, GL_FALSE);
```